# Showing negative values on progress bar in qt

Tags: qt5, progress-bar

I have 8 different progress bar. In the code below, im showing the positive values of my array. I want to display negative values also. How can i do it?
When i put else and write the other progress bar on gui, it didnt work true

```
if(dizi[1] > 0  || dizi[2] > 0 || dizi[3] > 0  || dizi[4] > 0)
        {
            ui->progressBarAx->setValue(dizi[1]);
            ui->progressBarAy->setValue(dizi[2]);
            ui->progressBarBx->setValue(dizi[3]);
            ui->progressBarBy->setValue(dizi[4]);

        }
```

Comment: You say you have 8 progress bars but your code seems to show 4.  If setValue accepts negative values then remove the if condition.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the method `setFormat(const QString &format)` to generate the text you need.

Example:

```
ui->progressBar->setValue(5);
ui->progressBar->setInvertedAppearance(true);
ui->progressBar->setFormat(QString("-") + QString("%p"));
ui->progressBar_2->setValue(51);
ui->progressBar_2->setInvertedAppearance(true);
ui->progressBar_3->setValue(5);
ui->progressBar_3->setFormat(QString("-") + QString("%p%")); //with %
ui->progressBar_3->setInvertedAppearance(false);
ui->progressBar_4->setValue(51);
ui->progressBar_4->setInvertedAppearance(false);
```

The method `setInvertedAppearance` is also interesting to show the progress inverted.

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot. Im reading some datas on serial port and im writing them on my gui which is progress bar. It stuck some times on one value, it doesnt refrest yourself. What can be the problem?

Comment: You're welcome! Difficult to say without looking into your code. Try to log the info your getting from your serial port. Maybe the problem is on the other side, the device that's writing into the serial port.

Comment: What do you mean with log the info

Comment: Sorry. I mean to show the information in the terminal instead the QProgressBar, for example.